# How to insert values from a list, into a tuple with python?

Tags: python

I have list

```
[2, 237, 3, 1]
```

And I also have tuples

```
[(0, 0, {'product_id': x, 'product_uom_qty': y}), (0, 0, {'product_id': x, 'product_uom_qty': y})]
```

Both of these are dynamically generated. I want the value of this list, to be inserted into the x and y of the tuples. like so

```
[(0, 0, {'product_id': 2, 'product_uom_qty': 237}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 3, 'product_uom_qty': 1})]
```

I know tuples are immutable, so I tried to assign the list a variable such as

```
test = [2, 237, 3, 1]
```

This leads to

```
[(0, 0, {'product_id': [2, 237, 3, 1], 'product_uom_qty': [2, 237, 3, 1]}), (0, 0, {'product_id': [2, 237, 3, 1], 'product_uom_qty': [2, 237, 3, 1]})]
```

I need a way to include specific values into the tuple, is there such a way to do this?

Comment: Post your code as well about how you are getting the last list.

Comment: Lists are mutable. Convert your tuple to a list: `lst=list(mytuple)`, then do your processing, then convert back:`mytuple=tuple(lst)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [2, 237, 3, 1]
b = [(0, 0, {'product_id': '', 'product_uom_qty': ''}), (0, 0, {'product_id': '',     'product_uom_qty': ''})]

start_index = 0
b = list(b)

for b_entry in b:
    end_index = start_index + len(b_entry[2]) - 1
    for value in range(start_index, end_index):
        b_entry[2]['product_id'] = a[value]
        b_entry[2]['product_uom_qty'] = a[value + 1]
    start_index += len(b_entry[2])

b = tuple(b)
print(b)
```

> ((0, 0, {'product_id': 2, 'product_uom_qty': 237}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 3, 'product_uom_qty': 1}))

This assumes the length of `a` is sufficient to fill the number of items in `b`. I assume you have no control over the input either - of course that would be a simpler solution. Tuples are immutable, but usually a simple typecast to list will allow you to work with them.

Comment: I want to thank you for providing such a clear and conscience answer. I am not able to control the input, but using your example I was able to do what I needed. Thank you.